# Can you import a .scss partial into .sass file?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, create-react-app, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to import Bootstrap's grid system into a create-react-app project that is using SASS.

I inherited this project from a previous developer, and I'm not super familiar with implementing Bootstrap/SASS.

This is my file structure:

[image]

Inside of App.sass, I have this code at the top of the file:

```
@import '../vars'
@import '../bootstrap_custom'
```

The styles are not importing correctly. I imagine it's related to the fact that I am importing .scss files into a .sass file, which I imagine is a big no-no.

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: There are converters for changing Sass to SCSS. Maybe that might be a better approach - convert your legacy Sass and be done with it.

Comment: Both types are handled by node-sass so this should not be a problem in general - though it depends on create-react-app blackbox. You can certainly eject and set whatever tests/loaders you like. Either way, what is the compile error? could be a path or missing mixins etc.also, try adding the extension as it may be setup for .sass only.